# Deep Linking Issue

Tags: android, deep-linking

I have a problem with deep linking. I have a website, and inside the `<head>` tag I put:

```
<link rel="alternate" href="android-app://com.myapp.borabora/appindex/boraboraapp" />
```

In my app's manifest file I have:

```
<activity
  android:name="com.myapp.borabora.FeedIndexing"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:exported="true"
  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >

  <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="appindex"
     data android:host="boraboraapp"/>
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

When I search for my website on Google, I can't see the menu that gives me the choice between opening it in Chrome or my app. Why? If i don't use custom scheme, everything it's ok, but i want to use this method:

```
<link rel="alternate" href="android-app://com.myapp.borabora/appindex/boraboraapp" />
```

Because I want to choose page for page.

Answer (score 0):

Google seems to be recommending that people use HTTP schemes rather than custom schemes. You can support both simultaneously though. Try adding an additional  element within your intent filter for the HTTP scheme:

```
<intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="appindex" android:host="boraboraapp"/>
    <!-- Support HTTP too -->
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="yourdomain.com"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Then change your web page  tag to:

```
<link rel="alternate" href="android-app://com.myapp.borabora/http/yourdomain.com/foo" />
```